# Grep on source code excluding build folders

Tags: linux, bash

I use grep to look for a variable usage or a function call in the following way

```
 grep -Rni <function_name>
```

However, the search also includes my build and build_debug folders.
Considering the case in which my code is structured as following

```
root/
  | 
  ->build
  | 
  ->build_debug
  |
  ->pkg_1
     |
     ->src
     |
     ->include
  ->pkg_2
     |
     ->src
     |
     ->include
```

How can I modify the query so that it does not look into build and build_debug?
Thanks!

Comment: There's this fancy new thing called "manual".

Comment: You're right. Apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep --exclude-dir build --exclude-dir build_debug -Rni
```